# How to give an injective function?

Tags: functions

Totally lost with this question :

> Give an injective function $f : 2^{\{0,1\}} \to \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$
>
> Can the codomain be written as {(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)}?

I'm not sure I understand the $2^{\{0,1\}}$ part?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Toally new to functions.

Comment: Yes on codomain; $2^{\{0,1\}}$ is the (four) subsets of $\{0,1\}.$

Comment: I guess I'm confused what "Give an injective function means". I know a function is injective when there are more that 1 elements in the domain that map to 1 codomain.

Comment: They want you to provide an explicit example of an injective function with the given domain and codomain. For instance, could you give an example of an injective function $g:\{0,1\}\to \{0,2,7\}$? (To practise giving examples of functions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $2^S$ denotes the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the set $S$. In your case,
$$ 2^{\{0,1\}} =\left\{ \emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\} \right\}$$

Similarly, $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$ denotes the [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product) of the set $\{0,1\}$ with itself; that is,
\begin{align}
\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} &= \left\{(x,y) \mid x,y \in \{0,1\} \right\} \\
&= \left\{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) \right\}
\end{align}

---

In response to your more recent comments, a function is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) if and only if it maps distinct elements in its domain to distinct element in its codomain. If $f$ is an injective function, then $$f(a) = f(b) \iff a = b $$
In your question, you want to create an injective function between the set $2^{\{0,1\}}$ and the set $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$. One such function would be \begin{align}
\emptyset &\mapsto (0,0) \\
\{0\} &\mapsto (1,0) \\
\{1\} &\mapsto (1,1) \\
\{0, 1\} &\mapsto (0,1) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Brian. I guess I'm confused what "Give an injective function means". I know a function is injective when there are more that 1 elements in the domain that map to 1 codomain

Comment: @Robin See my most recent edit.